# How to know the output of for loops inside other for loops and how many times outer and inner loop iterate?

Tags: java

Beginner JAVA coder here and eager to learn. I have tried using videos and other sources to help me understand this concept, but I cannot seem to grasp it fully. I have the following code:

```
for(int i=1; i<3; i++)
{ 
    for(int j =1; j<=3; j++{
        System.out.println(i+j);
    }
}
```

I'm being asked how many outer loops does it iterate? and how many inner loops?

I don't understand how the looping works. I do know that I have a value for j which is 1 and j too which is 1 too. However, I get confused on how to properly identify the output. Please help and share with me how I can dominate this.

Comment: Put more `System.out.println` in your code at different points, printing the values of `i` and `j`, to help you follow what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer loop starts first by setting i to 1, then the program enters the inner loop and sets j to 1 and prints 2 (which is 1 + 1). Then it goes back to the start of the inner loop and increments j and runs the print again with i=1, j=2. This is done until your condition for j is not true anymore (when j becomes > 3). Then it increments i and starts running the inner loop again starting with j=1. Once i becomes >=3 the program moves on. So you would get the following output:

```
2
3
4
3
4
5
```

All of that of course if you close the parenthesis in the inner loop :)

Answer (score 0):

When the outer loops does 1 loop, it executes the code inside the loop. The inner loop 3 times (j = 1, 2, 3) when that loop ends, it goes to the end of the outer loop, and i will be 1 bigger (1 -> 2). It will then do the inner loop all 3 times again. Then i isn't smaller than 3 anymore so it's finished.

So 2 times outer loop, 3 times inner loop which does 3 so 6 inner loops.

What you can do to output it properly is

```
system.out.println("i: " + i + ". j: " + j);
```

Comment: The outer loop iterates only twice. The conditional is a less than, as opposed to a less than or equals to.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop iterates twice. The inner loop iterates three times.

The outer loop iterates once for one, since 1 is less than 3, it increments 1 to 2, and then checks if 2 is less than 3. Since 2 is less than three, it iterates again, and then increments `i` once more. Finally, 3 is not less than 3, so there is no further iteration.

The inner loop iterates 3 times, for the same reason - the key difference is that the iterator is valid if it is less than or equal to 3 as opposed to less than 3.

So, the execution pattern goes as follows:

```
i=1, j=1
i=1, j=2
i=1, j=3
i=2, j=1
i=2, j=2
i=2, j=3
```

Answer (score 0):

//Make a counter for each one and every one loop count 1 for it , like this :

```
int inner=0; int outer=0;
for(int i=1; i<3; i++)
{ 
    for(int j =1; j<=3; j++){
     inner++; //or write : inner = inner + 1
    }
outer++;
}
System.out.printf("%s %d %s %d \n","The inner is",inner,"The outer is :",outer);
```